# TweetSharp - always need to auth (web app)?

Tags: c#, web-applications, twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

Do I always need to auth the user everytime i want to grant my app permission to use the user's twitter account? can i just grant once?

I used the following code..

```
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
    // Step 1 - Retrieve an OAuth Request Token
    TwitterService service = new TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");

    // This is the registered callback URL
    OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken("http://localhost:9090/AuthorizeCallback"); 

    // Step 2 - Redirect to the OAuth Authorization URL
    Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
    return new RedirectResult(uri.ToString(), false /*permanent*/);
}
```

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you only need to authenticate once, with TweetSharp or any other OAuth-based system, assuming you store the token data you get back from the authorization process.  You can then use that to perform any future queries.

I don't know enough about TweetSharp to post anything specific details about it, but Twitter has a page about their [usage of OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) to help get you started.